# No executable file is generated after catkin_make

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to use c++ to publish a Twist message. I added a couple of sentences introduced in wiki tutorials.

```
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(test src/test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(test beginner_tutorials_generate_message_cpp)
```

But after running catkin_make, there was no executable file generated. I do not know how to solve this problem.
I am using ROS Indigo running on Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226435/no-executable-file-is-generated-after-catkin_make/) by [percy_liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/25923/percy_liu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-02-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-02-12**:
`catkin_ws` is not a command. Did you do a `catkin_make`? Please follow the tutorials closely and try to understand what is done where...

**Comment by [percy_liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/25923/percy_liu/) on 2016-02-12**:
So sorry. I meant to write catkin_make not catkin_ws.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-02-12**:
the executable file should be in the `devel` folder, did you check there? Any errors in `catkin_make`?

**Comment by [percy_liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/25923/percy_liu/) on 2016-02-12**:
I checked `devel` folder and didn't find the executable file. When I run `catkin_make`, no error reported. There should be a message like "Build Target test". Actually, there was not.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-02-12**:
Do you see the `+++ processing catkin package:` and `==> add_subdirectory` outputs when you do `catkin_make`? Try a clean build (i.e. remove build and devel folder first). Does `roscd <YOURPACKAGE>`  work?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-02-12**:
Please add any commands that you run and their outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might need to add catkin_package() underneath those lines in your CMakeLists.txt. Check http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt.

---

Originally posted by [alee](https://answers.ros.org/users/26002/alee/) with karma: 194 on 2016-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0